# package javax.servlet does not exist even after setting the class path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, weblogic

Here's My code... a basic servlet code.

```
   //Servlet (interface)
     import javax.servlet.*;
     import java.io.*;
     public class DemoServlet1 implements Servlet
     {
     public void init(ServletConfig config)
     {  }
     public void service (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
                 throws ServletException, IOException
     {
            res.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            out.println("<html><body>");
            out.println("WELCOME SERVLET");
            out.println("</body></html>");
     }
     public void destroy()
     {}
     public ServletConfig getServletConfig()
     {
            return null;
     }
     public String getServletInfo()
     {
            return null;
     }
   }
```

COMPILING it.... it throws javax.servlet does not exist. 
The classpath and path are correct as I "ctrl c + ctrl v"ed it!!!
and its running on other machines, while its showing the following error response in mine.
I am using Win 7 (64bit)... not necessary i guess!!

```
  G:\2>set path = C:\beaB\jdk141_02\bin

  G:\2>set classpath = %classpath%;C:\beaB\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar

  G:2>javac DemoServlet1.java 

  DemoServlet1.java:2: package javax.servlet does not exist
  import javax.servlet.*;
  ^
  DemoServlet1.java:4: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Servlet
  public class DemoServlet1 implements Servlet
                                       ^
  DemoServlet1.java:6: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class ServletConfig
  location: class DemoServlet1

  public void init(ServletConfig config)
                     ^
  DemoServlet1.java:8: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class ServletRequest
  location: class DemoServlet1
  public void service (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
                 throws ServletException, IOException

  DemoServlet1.java:8: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class ServletResponse
  location: class DemoServlet1
  public void service (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)throws ServletExcep 
  tion, IOException
                                     ^
  DemoServlet1.java:8: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class ServletException
  location: class DemoServlet1
  public void service (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)throws ServletExcep
  tion, IOException
                                                                ^
  DemoServlet1.java:18: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class ServletConfig
  location: class DemoServlet1
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig()
           ^
  7 errors
```

What should I do??

Comment: You can provide the classpath in the javac command itself like 'javac -cp C:\beaB\weblogic81\server\lib\\*.jar DemoServlet1.java'

Answer (score 1):

You should have `servlet-api.jar` in the classpath. It should be present in `weblogic81\server\lib\` directory.

Answer (score 0):

which version of weblogic are you using, i think they moved it to moudles/ folder ....
please see inside the modules folder you will find javax.servlet_xxxxx.jar

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath does not have servlet-api.jar.

If u use Eclipse .

Right click the project  -> Build path - > configure build path  - > Add External jars -> browse the path where you have this jar and click ok..

If you are using tomcat server then you can find this jar in the **lib** folder of apache tomcat folder

Answer (score 0):

```
set classpath = C:\beaB\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar .
```

This will work you can check whether javax folder exist inside `weblogic.jar` or not simply by extracting `weblogic.jar`. Make sure that you are not setting class path as `:-`

```
set classpath = "C:\beaB\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar" .
```

There must not be double quotes as `""`.