# Compiling servlet: package javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: java, servlets

I have a problem with this servlet program while compiling it on cmd,I have     set class path of weblogic.jar file by using this on cmd - `set     classpath=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\weblogic.jar;`

My code is-

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
public class DemoServlet1 implements Servlet 
{
public void init(ServletConfig con)
{}
public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws     ServletException,IOException
{
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("hello servlet !!!!");
    out.println("</body></html>");
}
public void destroy()
{}
public ServletConfig getServletConfig()
{
    return null;
}
public String getServletInfo()
{
    return null;
}
}
```

Error message-

```
    C:\javaharsh\Demo>set class     path=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\w
    eblogic.jar;

    C:\javaharsh\Demo>javac DemoServlet1.java
    DemoServlet1.java:1: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    ^
    DemoServlet1.java:2: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
    import javax.servlet.*;
    ^
   DemoServlet1.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    public class DemoServlet1 implements Servlet
                                     ^
    symbol: class Servlet
  DemoServlet1.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        public void init(ServletConfig con)
                         ^
    symbol:   class ServletConfig
    location: class DemoServlet1
    DemoServlet1.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws Servle
    tException,IOException
                            ^
    symbol:   class ServletRequest
    location: class DemoServlet1
    DemoServlet1.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws Servle
    tException,IOException
                                               ^
    symbol:   class ServletResponse
    location: class DemoServlet1
    DemoServlet1.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws Servle
     tException,IOException
                                                                          ^
    symbol:   class ServletException
    location: class DemoServlet1
    DemoServlet1.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        public ServletConfig getServletConfig()
               ^
    symbol:   class ServletConfig
    location: class DemoServlet1
   8 errors
```

Comment: error messge-   DemoServlet1.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        public ServletConfig getServletConfig()
               ^
  symbol:   class ServletConfig
  location: class DemoServlet1
8 errors

Comment: I have already set the class path of weblogic.jar file

Answer (score 0):

You should have servlet-api.jar in the classpath. Also refer the following link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239170/package-javax-servlet-does-not-exist-even-after-setting-the-class-path)